# What is a quick and easy way to find an alternative axis of symmetry?

Tags: organic-chemistry, symmetry

[image]

According to a question in my book (1​*R*,3​*R*)-1,3-dichloro-2,2-bis[(*S*)-chloro(<sup>2</sup>H<sub>1</sub>)methyl](1,3-<sup>2</sup>H<sub>2</sub>)propane has an S4 alternative axis symmetry. I tried trial-and-error method using an axis that passes through only the top group straight down, one that is a horizontal line across the screen and some others but couldn't find it. How exactly do I do this?And also this is a JEE practice question and I need to do it in at the most a minute or two.

Comment: The only way to get good at 3D visualization is to practice. Various books on group symmetry will have a flow chart, but I could never remember the thing. Typically we could use the "unmarked" character tables for the test in class.

Comment: @MaxW what is an unmarked character table? In my book actually just the definitions of plane of symmetry,centre, axis and alternating axis of symmetry is covered

Comment: "unmarked" means that you didn't write cheat notes all over it.

Comment: @MaxW is there a way of doing it without character tables? I'm not exactly sure what they are but I don't think they are in my syllabus

Comment: The S4c operation is a rotation by 90 degrees and reflection in the perpendicular plane. Have a look at  the answer https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/58609/understanding-group-theory-easily-and-quickly/58613#58613 and also you can practice adding symmetry elements if you search for www.molecule-viewer.com and look at molecules under the  S4 point group for examples of the S4 operation.

Comment: Spatial perception is not an easy thing to teach you because there are some many cases. Building a model will likely start helping you to visualize the symmetry elements.