# Point group specific definition

Tags: spectroscopy, theoretical-chemistry, molecules, symmetry

Does the term only refer to molecules that have the same symmetry elements or exactly the same symmetry operations. Online I see that its the same symmetry operation however my professor's slides show only symmetry elements.

Or is it depend on the writer; Dnh refers only to symmetry elements but D3h refers to symmetry operations but they are both point groups?

Comment: Each element corresponds to each operation, so doesn't same elements imply same operations?

Comment: More precisely, each element corresponds to a set of operations. For example one $C_3$ symmetry axis implies three operations $(C_3)^0 \equiv E$, $(C_3)^1$, and $(C_3)^2$ (notation?). But yes, same symmetry elements corresponds to same symmetry operations.

Comment: Have a look at this answer https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/58609/understanding-group-theory-easily-and-quickly/58613#58613. which should explain things