# What does the order of a class mean in a character table?

Tags: crystallography, group-theory

I am not from a chemistry background. I am trying to see how the symmetry operations affect the stiffness tensor which led me in the path of understanding character tables. I am looking at the character table for C6v group and I cannot understand what the factor 2 for C6(z) means. Is it representative of the fact that I can rotate in clockwise and anticlockwise direction?

Please let me know if you need any further information. [image]

Comment: Yes.$\mathstrut$

Comment: Shouldn't C2(z) also have a factor of 2 then?

Comment: No, because rotating for $180^\circ$ clockwise and anticlockwise is the same thing.

Comment: This answer might help in general https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/58609/understanding-group-theory-easily-and-quickly/58613#58613

Comment: @IvanNeretin That makes sense. Thank you

Comment: @porphyrin Thank you. This is very helpful.