# How to determine the characters of px atomic orbital in C4v point group?

Tags: molecular-orbital-theory, group-theory

How to determine the characters of *p*x atomic orbital in $\text{C}_{\text{4v}}$ point group? I understand (*p*x,*p*y) is a set of basis function of *E*, and *p*x and *p*y are mixed by $\text{C}_4$ and $\sigma_{\text{d}}$. However, based on the figure below, how can I determine the characters of only *p*x orbital? Are the characters the same as those of *E*?

[image: px]

Comment: Operate on the orbital with each of the symmetry operations, $\sigma_v$ etc and compare them with the irreps for each symmetry species in the point group, count 1 for unchanged , -1 if changed,  see https://molecule-viewer.com/ for many examples. A few molecules in each point group also have orbitals included.

Comment: @porphyrin Yes, I understand this, but for the px orbital in the figure, $\sigma_\text{d}$ will transform it into py orbital, does this count as zero? Also for the two $\sigma_\text{v}$ operations, one character is 1 and the other is -1, so for the overall $2\sigma_\text{v}$ operation in the character table, does it count as 0?

Comment: Yes zero, also look at the third column in a point group, see entries for x, y, z and $R_x $ etc so you can check your answers.

Comment: @porphyrin Thanks. However, for $C_{4v}$ point group $p_x$ is a basis function of the doubly degenerate irreducible representation, is it correct to consider how only one of the basis functions transform? Since the calculators to decompose reducible representatons just return error, if I consider $p_x$ as a reducible representation.

Comment: see the last part of this answer for a worked example. https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/58609/understanding-group-theory-easily-and-quickly/58613#58613 , a fuller example is given by R. Carter, chapter 3 'Molecular Symmetry and group theory' publ Wiley.

Comment: Since the question has received 0 answers or votes here, I wonder if you considered asking it at MMSE?